# Create new Object/instance each Module call, variables still retain initial value

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small script which will get called multiple times, and take different arguments each time.

My problem is that things inside the first call still hang around the second call, here's an example where I override 'somethings' on the first call but *not* the second:

```
var Module = (function () {

'use strict';

var somethings = '';

var exports = {};

exports.init = function (something) {
    if (something) {
        somethings = something;
    }
    console.log(somethings);
};

return exports;

})();

Module.init('Hiya');
Module.init();
```

The thing is here 'Hiya' is logged both times. I know why, but I don't think I'm using the right JS pattern, I need completely new variables for each call. Can anyone recommend a better pattern to me? I'd highly appreciate it and want to learn how to write better JS!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dd4Kk)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the variable again, remove the private variable and just use the function paramether

```
var Module = (function () {

'use strict';
var somethings = [];
var exports = {};

exports.init = function (something) {
    if (something) {
        somethings.push(something);
        console.log(something);
    }

};

return exports;

})();

Module.init('Hiya');
Module.init();
```

In this instance there is only one thing logged, and the message isn't stored because you need a new one each time.

EDIT

I updated the code to save your parameter each time

Comment: I will need the variable again, this was just a real quick example of what's happening rather than the real code :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables you want to renew at each call inside the returned function, and only declare outside the variables that should hang around:

```
var Module = (function () {
    'use strict';
    var exports = {};
    exports.init = function (something) {
        var somethings = '';
        if (something) {
            somethings = something;
        }
        console.log(somethings);
    };
    return exports;
})();
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem here is I need to access the variables privately outside of the init function, so I can access it outside the scope with another private function.

Comment: @Halcyon991 Then it depends. Can you include the code of the other private functions, to clarify what you are trying to achieve?